# Wordpress - Custom Header

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, wordpress-theming

Im trying to get a custom header to my wordpress theme.

```
    $args = array(
    'width'         => 1920,
    'height'        => 800,
    'default-image' => get_template_directory_uri() . '/images/header.jpg',
    'uploads'       => true,
); add_theme_support( 'custom-header', $args );
```

Added that to my functions.php and want the default-image to be the image that show if its no image set in admin.

But it wont show anything. the "img src" is empty.

Tried to upload a image then it shows, what could be the problem?

```
<img src="<?php echo header_image(); ?>" height="<?php echo get_custom_header()->height; ?>" width="<?php echo get_custom_header()->width; ?>" alt="" />
```

Using that in my front-page.php (the width and height is set correctly).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I couldn't find anything wrong with your code. However you can try this below. It always works well for me.

```
<?php if (get_header_image()) { ?>
    <img src="<?php header_image(); ?>" alt="<?php bloginfo('name'); ?>">
<?php } else { ?>
    <img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/images/header.jpg" alt="<?php bloginfo('name'); ?>">
<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
<img src="<?php echo( get_header_image() ); ?>" height="<?php echo get_custom_header()->height; ?>" width="<?php echo get_custom_header()->width; ?>" alt="" />
```

Comment: Code only answers can generally benefit from some explanation.

Comment: While this answer is probably correct and useful, it is preferred if you include some explanation along with it to explain how it helps to solve the problem. This becomes especially useful in the future, if there is a change (possibly unrelated) that causes it to stop working and users need to understand how it once worked.